# Operator overloading in template in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I read following code from somewhere:

```
template<class T> class A {
    T a;
public:
    A(T x):a(x) {}
    operator T() const {return a;}   // what is point here?
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    A<int> a = A<int>(5);
    int n = a;
    cout << n;
    return 0;
}
```

What does below line mean?

> operator T() const {return a;}

Comment: This would be a well posed question if you had `#include <iostream>` `std::cout`/`using namespace std;` and `main` instead of `tmain`

Comment: @awoodland I would argue that his question is understandable and unambiguous, even if it makes use of nonstandard, and missing code.

Comment: @Mooing duck - non standard and missing raises the barrier to testing things for answers and it's got to be worth getting in the habit of asking great questions.

Comment: `worth getting in the habit`, know what?  I changed my mind.  I agree.

Comment: The thing that made me post that comment was I skimmed over the question thought "wow, that's pretty well written" and then noticed that it was only tantalisingly close to being a great way to ask the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> operator T() const {return a;}

This is the [typecast operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts48df3y.aspx). It'll implicitly convert the class instance to `T`. In the example code you've posted this conversion is being performed at the line

> int n = a;

Comment: Clear answer. Thanks Praetorian!

Comment: @Bill Li - In `C++11` you'll be able to use the `explicit` keyword with those just like you can with one argument constructors. That way you can still get the conversion but it will never happen implicitly.

Answer (score 3):

It means if you want to convert an instance into a `T` you can use this operator, which here returns a copy of the private member.

In your example code that is how you can assign `a`, which is of type `A<int>` to an `int` directly. Try removing the `operator T()` and see how that fails to compile, with an error about assigining `A<T>` to an `int`.

With the non `explicit` constructor (the opposite of marking a constructor `explicit`) there too it makes this type behave a lot like the template type itself in a number of circumstances. In effect you've wrapped a `T` inside another class that behaves like a `T` when it needs to. You could extend this to do other, more useful things like monitoring/logging/restricting the use of real instances by hiding them behind something which controlled them.

Also notice how you can change `A<int> a = A<int>(5);` to simply `A<int> a = 5;` because of the implicit constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it trying to overload cast? The explicit syntax would be: int n = (int)a; I also agree with your point regarding explicit constructor.

Comment: the `explicit` I mentioned only applies to the constructor and has nothing to do with `operator T()`, which is what allows the assignment. `int n = (int)a;` is just a cast, which happens to be a C-style cast too. (For C++ prefer `static_cast` and friends)

Answer (score -5):

It's basically making a functor - which is an object with function semantics.  That means you can call the object just like a function as a replacement in places where you may have used a function - its a generic programming concept.

It's beneficial because you can have multiple instances of that function-object (functor) and they can each maintain their own state, where as if you had a straight-up function then it could only maintain state via static variables, and it would thus not be re-entrant (you only ever get one instance of a static variable).

Functors are heavily used in STL algorithms as an extra optional parameter.

Comment: -1: the object does not overload `operator()`, so it is not a function object.

Comment: Nope, a functor would have the signature `<return-type> operator()( <input-params> )`